# WSO2 EI, Iterate through JSON Array

Tags: json, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I'm creating simple REST API by WSO2 EI. I'm sending this json:

```
{
    "array": ["Hello", "this", "is", "an", "arrray", "1", 3, 4]
}
```

I want to iterate over each element in array and show them in logs.

I have created that kind of sequence for it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="for_each_test_seq_in" trace="enable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <property expression="json-eval($.array)" name="array"
    scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    <log level="full">
        <property expression="get-property('array')" name="ARRAY" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    </log>
    <iterate expression="get-property('array')" id="iterate_one" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd">
        <target sequence="anon">
            <sequence>
                <log level="full"/>
            </sequence>
        </target>
    </iterate>
    <respond/>
</sequence>
```

When I launch it, I get this error message:

```
[2017-09-19 16:06:40,236] [] ERROR - SynapseXPath Evaluation of the XPath expression get-property('array') resulted in an error
org.jaxen.UnresolvableException: No Such Function get-property
    at 
org.jaxen.SimpleFunctionContext.getFunction(SimpleFunctionContext.java:127)
    at org.jaxen.ContextSupport.getFunction(ContextSupport.java:242)
    at org.jaxen.Context.getFunction(Context.java:216)
    ...
```

I don't understand why `get-property` is unknown for it. I know that `get-property` is a XPath function.

I just want to iterate over each element of `array` element and do something with them.

Is it possible?

Comment: XPATH function get-property() is builtin into synapse engine to work with xml.

Comment: Use json-eval and jsonpath expressions https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/JSON+Support

Comment: Most probably you meant for-each mediator instead of iterator. Mediator iterator has different logic (check documentation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is implementation.

WSO API of rest service. Receive request,  log body of message, process over sequence and send back to client. Sequence **for_each_test_seq_in** doesn't change content of message

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/array" name="array" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST">
        <inSequence>
            <log>
                <property expression="json-eval($.*)" name="==============="/>
            </log>
            <sequence key="for_each_test_seq_in"/>
            <loopback/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

This is sequence code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="for_each_test_seq_in" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <property expression="json-eval($.array)" name="array" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <log level="full">
        <property expression="get-property('array')" name="ARRAY" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    </log>
    <foreach expression="//array">
        <sequence>
            <log level="full"/>
        </sequence>
    </foreach>
</sequence>
```

Example of post request on picture underneath
[image: SoapUI request response]

Log of server states

```
[2017-10-16 23:55:18,375] [EI-Core]  INFO - LogMediator To: /array, MessageID: urn:uuid:648f7e51-4c71-48d7-8d09-f914ce29a867, Direction: request, =============== = [[34,234,"example",56.3,"mom"]]
[2017-10-16 23:55:18,379] [EI-Core]  INFO - LogMediator To: /array, MessageID: urn:uuid:648f7e51-4c71-48d7-8d09-f914ce29a867, Direction: request, ARRAY = [34,234,"example",56.3,"mom"], Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><jsonObject><array>34</array><array>234</array><array>example</array><array>56.3</array><array>mom</array></jsonObject></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
[2017-10-16 23:55:18,380] [EI-Core]  INFO - LogMediator To: /array, MessageID: urn:uuid:648f7e51-4c71-48d7-8d09-f914ce29a867, Direction: request, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><array>34</array></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
[2017-10-16 23:55:18,381] [EI-Core]  INFO - LogMediator To: /array, MessageID: urn:uuid:648f7e51-4c71-48d7-8d09-f914ce29a867, Direction: request, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><array>234</array></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
[2017-10-16 23:55:18,381] [EI-Core]  INFO - LogMediator To: /array, MessageID: urn:uuid:648f7e51-4c71-48d7-8d09-f914ce29a867, Direction: request, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><array>example</array></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
[2017-10-16 23:55:18,381] [EI-Core]  INFO - LogMediator To: /array, MessageID: urn:uuid:648f7e51-4c71-48d7-8d09-f914ce29a867, Direction: request, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><array>56.3</array></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
[2017-10-16 23:55:18,382] [EI-Core]  INFO - LogMediator To: /array, MessageID: urn:uuid:648f7e51-4c71-48d7-8d09-f914ce29a867, Direction: request, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><array>mom</array></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

First line is represented by

```
<log><property expression="json-eval($.*)" name="==============="/></log>
 ...=============== = [[34,234,"example",56.3,"mom"]]
```

Second log line is result of part of code in sequence

```
<log level="full">
    <property expression="get-property('array')" name="ARRAY"/>
</log>
  ....Direction: request, ARRAY = [34,234,"example",56.3,"mom"], Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><jsonObject><array>34</array><array>234</array><array>example</array><array>56.3</array><array>mom</array></jsonObject></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

As you can see it has two representations. One is in json format:

```
ARRAY = [34,234,"example",56.3,"mom"]
```

Second is in xml notation according rules described in https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/JSON+Support (chapter **XML representation of JSON payloads**)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
   <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
           <soapenv:Body>
               <jsonObject>
                   <array>34</array>
                   <array>234</array>
                   <array>example</array>
                   <array>56.3</array>
                   <array>mom</array>
           </jsonObject>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Documentation state that it is possible to apply xpath on json payload if you consider json representation in xml. Using this just apply for each to get each part of array using xpath **//array**

As result original array, in xml representation,  is spitted by each element of array and logged in console. You can see it in rest of logs

```
LogMediator To: /array, MessageID: urn:uuid:6...  Envelope: <soapenv:Body><array>34</array></soapenv:Body>
LogMediator To: /array, MessageID: urn:uuid:6.... Envelope: <soapenv:Body><array>234</array></soapenv:Body>
LogMediator To: /array, MessageID: urn:uuid:6...  Envelope: <soapenv:Body><array>example</array></soapenv:Body>
LogMediator To: /array, MessageID: urn:uuid:6.... Envelope: <soapenv:Body><array>56.3</array></soapenv:Body>
LogMediator To: /array, MessageID: urn:uuid:6.... Envelope: <soapenv:Body><array>mom</array></soapenv:Body>
```